# Firebase: Link anonymous user with provider redirect

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am sorry to say that I have a hard time understanding the documentation on how to link an anonymous account with a provider, for example Github.

The documentation says that you first need to get the access token of the provider, but without doing a `signInWith`... but you have to do that to get the access token.

So how do you get the access token of a provider without doing `signInWith`?

And related to that, the user will have to approve these details and this might have to be done with a redirect. How would you get, when the user is redirected back, a reference to both the provider details and the anonymous details?

**EDIT**
I found the `linkWith` and `linkWithRedirect` apis after some searching. Gave google feedback on updating the docs as they are seriously confusing on this part, not even mentioning this API.

Comment: What platform are you using? In web it is easy. In other platforms, you will need to implement an OAuth flow to get the GitHub access token.

Comment: Thanks for response, I actually found the `linkWith` and `linkWithRedirect` API after some searching. Gave feedback on highlighting this better on feedback form to Google :)